# Metro App - Smooth SemanticZoom Transition

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, semantic-zoom

I am working on creating a Metro Style App in Windows 8 using the HTML5/JavaScript framework. My issue is that when I am in semantic zoom, if my user pinches to zoom in or out, the transition is not smooth like the start screen. Rather, the user pinches, then the semantic zoom transitions from zoomedin to zoomedout. I would like it to be like the start screen, where the user can use his fingers to control HOW zoomed out/in the content is, and it zooms out and in at the same time as the user's fingers pinch. Interestingly enough, the [C#/XAML semanticzoom sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e) includes this funciontality, but the [JavaScript sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-grouping-and-6d032cc1) does not. Is there a reason for this? Is it possible to implement this functionality without totally rewriting semanticzoom.

I have tried using the -ms-content-zoom CSS on the views, but it doesn't work.

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the native functionality of semantic zoom, you shouldn't need to code anything extra. To help more, here are the code samples for [WinJS Semantic Zoom](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-grouping-and-6d032cc1).

Comment: Well, thats just the issue, its only native when in C#.